# Using Python to invoke smart contract

Tags: contract-invocation, testnets, python

I'm currently writing a thesis on a simulation of a peer to peer electricity market. The payments between the agents of the simulation would be settled through an Eth smart contract. I would like to run the simulation of the marketplace (supply/demand of agents, order book) in Python. I have zero experience coding smart contracts.

I was wondering if there was any way to invoke a smart contract using Python code. What I am envisioning is Python invoking a smart contract in an Ethereum test net which would keep track of how much Ethereum each agent has.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use web3.py to work with ethereum and smart contract similar to web3js

https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/